# Can't install ros-fuerte-desktop-full

Tags: ros, installation, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,I'm a freshman using the ROS.Now i have a problem with installing the ROS.
The error is :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  ros-fuerte-desktop-full: Depends: ros-fuerte-geometry-tutorials (= 0.1.3-s1348604104~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-orocos-kinematics-dynamics (= 0.2.3-s1347124369~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-slam-gmapping (= 1.2.7-s1347149853~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-simulator-gazebo (= 1.6.16-s1347143896~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-visualization (= 1.8.14-s1348597315~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-vision-opencv (= 1.8.6-s1348605251~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-perception-pcl (= 1.2.3-s1347138723~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-geometry-experimental (= 0.2.3-s1347135025~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-common-tutorials (= 0.2.3-s1348604186~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-image-pipeline (= 1.8.5-s1348607270~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-geometry-visualization (= 0.1.1-s1347141526~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-stage (= 1.6.6-s1347134700~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-image-transport-plugins (= 1.8.2-s1348607399~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-robot-model (= 1.8.1-s1347134620~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-geometry (= 1.8.2-s1347129500~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-visualization-tutorials (= 0.6.3-s1348598867~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-laser-pipeline (= 1.4.4-s1347142720~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-navigation (= 1.8.3-s1347147340~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

So what is the problem with my installation? My ubuntu version is 10.04
Thank you very much!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45550/can%27t-install-ros-fuerte-desktop-full/) by [qnan1983](https://answers.ros.org/users/3361/qnan1983/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-10-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2012-10-10**:
What version of Ubuntu are you using?

**Comment by [qnan1983](https://answers.ros.org/users/3361/qnan1983/) on 2012-10-10**:
10.04 lucid

**Comment by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on 2012-10-10**:
i also met the same problem when i tried to install Diamondback on 10.04. So i upgrade my ubuntu to 12.04 and now i'm having fun with Fuerte on it.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-10**:
What's the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list`?

**Comment by [qnan1983](https://answers.ros.org/users/3361/qnan1983/) on 2012-10-11**:
this is the content in ros-latest.list :deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu lucid main

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-11**:
Did you try a `sudo apt-get update` before the apt-get install command?

**Comment by [qnan1983](https://answers.ros.org/users/3361/qnan1983/) on 2012-10-11**:
I followed the install instruction on ros wiki,no doubt the process was right

**Comment by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on 2012-10-11**:
Very similar question to [this thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/33585/unable-to-install-ros-on-ubuntu-1204/#33604)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a [similar issue](http://answers.ros.org/question/44388/has-anyone-been-able-to-install-furte-on-an-x86_64-platform/) which boiled down to one uninstallable package.

This package was uninstallable because multiverse sources.list (was commented out).

(with that said, I did make the change, installed ROS and apparently did a subsequent update because the line is no longer commented out).

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2012-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2